# Invalid bus width error while boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I was trying to install Ubuntu 20.04, but I accord with this error when start booting flash memory.

[image: ing]

Comment: Are you using a SD cvard?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm trying to boot Ubuntu via flash memory. And my system hard is SSD

Comment: "flash memory" says nothing useful, hence why I specifically asked whether or not you were trying to boot the installer/live media in a SD card. This is because in most USB connected SD/MMC card readers it works just like if using an USB stick while with other types it simply doesn't. The error shown can be due to that or just a faulty SD card. So, again, **is the live/installation media a SD card?** If so, are you using an USB adapter or an internal reader?

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly and while at that also add hardware specifications and correct the text, namely the release number which is **22.04**. Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks for your kindness reply. Yes i'm using sd card and internal reader

Comment: So, nothing elser to add to the previous comment. Use an USB stick.

Answer (score 2):

success!

try terminal:
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub

changes:

...

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intremap=no_x2apic_optout nox2apic pci=nomsi pcie_aspm=force"

...

#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

acpi=off
...